# Wrap different subclasses with same additional field

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

Let's say I have some abstract class `User`, and then subclasses `Owner` and `Client`. Each of the two subclasses have some specific fields, but they both inherit common fields from the `User`. This is all OK, but in a specific situation I'd like to be able to wrap any instance of `User` with another field. Here is the example.

**User.java**

```
public abstract class User {

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String name;

}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client extends User {

    private String salary;

    private String profit;

}
```

**Owner.java**

```
public class Owner extends User {

    private int numberOfClients;

    private double averageClientSalary;

}
```

Now in a specific case, I'd like to be able to wrap such instances with a login token. So no matter if it is a `Client` or the `Owner` instance, it should receive another field `loginToken` on top of all it's fields.

The use-case would be something like this.

```
Client client = new Client(email, password, name, salary, profit);

String loginToken = "123abc456";

UserLogin clientLogin = new UserLogin(client);
clientLogin.setLoginToken(loginToken);

// now this should be possible
clientLogin.getEmail(); // base class field
clientLogin.getSalary(); // derived class field
clientLogin.getLoginToken(); // field from a wrapper
```

So this `UserLogin` should be able to receive any subclass of `User` as constructor argument, and remain all of it's fields, just add the extra one, ie. `loginToken`.

Would something like this be possible and how?

Basically, what would the `UserLogin` class look like?

Comment: Not possible. The type `UserClient` has its own interface.

Comment: Read about mixins in Scala, you would like that

Comment: Why didn't you put login token in `User` base? Because token is of no concern to it. Similarly I would say specific user's implementation details are of no concern to `UserLogin`. It's sole responsibility should be set up a user login mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

For base class fields and wrapper class fields (or to be precise getters as `private` fields are not accessible from subclasses) , you can add delegation methods in the wrapper `UserLogin` class.
But you could not use getters of the subclass as the wrapper manipulates a `User` declared variable.

```
public class UserLogin {

    private User user;
    private String token;

    public UserLogin(User user, String token) {
        this.user = user;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }    

    public String getLoginToken() {
        return token;
    }

    // not possible for derived fields
    public String getSalary() {
        return user.getSalary();
    }

}
```

As workaround to do such a thing you could make `UserLogin` a generic class that provides a method that returns an instance of the specific `User` class.

For example :

```
public class UserLogin<T extends User> {

    private T user;
    private String token;

    public UserLogin(T user, String token) {
        this.user = user;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    public T getConcreteUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getLoginToken() {
        return token;
    }    

}
```

You can now invoke :

```
UserLogin<Client> clientLogin = new UserLogin<>(new Client(), "token");

clientLogin.getEmail(); 
clientLogin.getConcreteUser()
           .getSalary(); 
clientLogin.getLoginToken();
```